Prevent Chrome password manager from appearing when I sign in
I am using puppeteer in NodeJS to automate the browser and perform a login.
Once logged in, the Chrome password manager box appears, but I want to prevent it from appearing.
I have tried passing '--password_manager_enabled=false' as an argument, an option I found in comments in previous questions on this site, but even so, Chrome's password manager continues to appears and ask if I want to save the password.
The options I currently manage look like this:
let browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    ars: ['--no-sandbox', '--password_manager_enabled=false'],
    ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--enable-automation"],
    headless: false
});



I have edited my post, now I think it is clearer.
My goal is that the browser password manager does not appear.

Thanks. Do you have the site (or a site) that reproduces this manager box? Can you link to the previous questions/comments you're referring to?

You can disable the password manager in the Chrome profile

I should not use any profile, the browser should always start from scratch.

The flags that have worked for me in the past are --use-mock-keychain and --password-store=basic.
A good source for finding chromium flags is this site maintained by Peter Beverloo at Google.

--password-store=basic works, as long as you don't use ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--enable-automation"],
In my case, if I need to use this option

Although the --password-store=basic option works to disable the password manager, in my case it doesn't work because I have to use ignoreDefaultArgs: ["--enable-automation"] and when I set that option the password manager appears again.
